# Unable to populate excel cell with correct date format

Tags: excel, scala, date

I am trying to populate a excel cell with date in dd.MM.yyyy format.

```
val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

And then I try to pass following value to xsl writer API as:

```
dateFormat.parse("24.06.2020")
```

But in output xsl file I see it as "24/06/2020".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just change the format.

Comment: I dont get you. I have provided the format when I define SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Change the format in the Excel sheet.

Comment: But I have to do it programmatically.

Comment: What I mean is that Excel stores a date in the cells. The format does not matter. It's just a question of selecting the cells and changing the format.

Comment: To do it programmatically depends on the API you are using and if it provides the function call to do that.